# fatal error LNK1112 while upgrading from VS 2005 (v80) to VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

I have a VS Win32 based project in VS 2005 and it was used to build correctly in v80. Now I have upgraded it to VS 2012 with some C# projects that build correctly in v110. I have installed Daffodil tool chain to build the old C++ projects in v80 configuration. Now when I build it with v80 (with win32) all goes well. But when I build it with v80  (configuration x64) there occurs a link error "LNK 1112" and when build with v100 i get TRACKER : error TRK0002.

I have "Target Machine" set to x64 in linker->advanced settings. I have chosen x64 as Active solution plateform. Cant figure out why this error occurs?

I want my project to be built on x64.
Also there are no target machine set in Linker->Command line properties

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: check the following link..a similar problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980082/tracing-lnk1112-error-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: LNK1112 occurs when you try to link a 32-bit object file or library into a 64-bit program.  You'll need to ensure that *everything* is built to 64-bit.